# PHPMailer is not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, email

I have developed a site in PHP and added a PHPMailer function for my contact us page but the mailer functionality is not working. Contacted with support team but they didn't help me tried a lot with that.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_contact']))  
    {
       require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
       $to = "gmail@gmail.com";
       $name = $_POST['uname'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
       $companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
       $country = $_POST['country2'];
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail->isSMTP();                                      
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"; 
       $mail->Port = 465;
       $mail->IsHTML(true);                                     
       $mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com";                 
       $mail->Password = "PASSword1@3";   
       $message = array();    
       $message[] = 'Name  :  '.trim($name).' ';        
       $message[]='Phone  :  '.trim($phone).' ';   
       $message[]='Email  :  '.trim($email).' '; 
       $message[]='Company Name  :  '.trim($companyname).' ';    
       $message[]='Country  :  '.trim($country).' ';    
       $message = implode('<br/>', $message);           
       $mail->SetFrom($email);
       $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
       $mail->Body = $message;
       $mail->AddAddress($to); 
       if(!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = "Error while sending email";
            $msgclass = 'bg-danger';
            header("Location: /");
            die();    
       } 
       else {
          $msg = 'A mail with recovery instruction has sent to your email.';
          $msgclass = 'bg-success';
       }     
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you have to use godaddy's relay servers to send email from: https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-servers-email-relay-server-16601

Comment: @NiteRain not getting how to use

Comment: You set the PHPmailer host to godaddy's relay server.   You set up SMTPAuth to true, set the port to 465, set SMTPSecure to ssl, you put in your username and password to authenticate.

Comment: @NiteRain when i contacted support team they said to keep host as local host

Comment: @NiteRain relay-hosting.secureserver.net is this the godaddy relay host

Comment: @NiteRain after the changes got this error 2019-02-23 09:57:04 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Let's check your mail server on local host.  can you telnet to localhost on port 25?

Comment: @unable to understand what you are saying

Comment: If they are allowing people to email from their hosted servers, then you should be able to connect to the SMTP server by telneting into port 25 on localhost.

Comment: @NiteRain if i change port to 25 and host to localhost  then also its didnt work

Comment: If you aren't able to connect to that server, then there is a server issue.  You should hit up godaddy to make sure they set you up with that access.

Comment: Go to the command line, and type: telnet localhost 25 if you are connected, you are allowed to type helo mattie.com

Comment: Getting a lot of mixed signals from godaddy. https://www.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/Using-phpmailer-to-send-a-contact-us-form-from-cPanel-email/td-p/111175  Seems they have several products.  But most of the documentation I see online says you have to connect to a relay to send email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->isSMTP();                                      
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
   $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';
   $mail->Host = "localhost"; 
   $mail->Port = 25;
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Solved the issue with this update in SMTP

Answer (score 0):

u used gmail,u should set host to smtp.gmail.com, SMTPSecure to ssl,SMTPAuth to true,port to 465,u alse should use the app password,that u can see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

Comment: Done with this as well getting same error 2019-02-23 10:00:42 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: now u used the gmail, u cannot use the godaddy's relay server.u should use the google SMTP server,alse the gmail password u should use app passwords

Comment: at the beginning i have tried with gmail host when i got this server i used godaddy server after contacting support team